# Fastest technique to deleting duplicate data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, etl

After searching stackoverflow.com I found several questions asking how to remove duplicates, but none of them addressed speed.

In my case I have a table with 10 columns that contains 5 million exact row duplicates.  In addition, I have at least a million other rows with duplicates in 9 of the 10 columns.  My current technique is taking (so far) **3 hours** to delete these 5 million rows.  Here is my process:

```
-- Step 1:  **This step took 13 minutes.** Insert only one of the n duplicate rows into a temp table
select
    MAX(prikey) as MaxPriKey, -- identity(1, 1)
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d,
    e,
    f,
    g,
    h,
    i
into #dupTemp
FROM sourceTable
group by
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d,
    e,
    f,
    g,
    h,
    i
having COUNT(*) > 1
```

Next,

```
-- Step 2: **This step is taking the 3+ hours**
-- delete the row when all the non-unique columns are the same (duplicates) and
-- have a smaller prikey not equal to the max prikey
delete 
from sourceTable
from sourceTable
inner join #dupTemp on  
    sourceTable.a = #dupTemp.a and
    sourceTable.b = #dupTemp.b and
    sourceTable.c = #dupTemp.c and
    sourceTable.d = #dupTemp.d and
    sourceTable.e   = #dupTemp.e and
    sourceTable.f = #dupTemp.f and
    sourceTable.g = #dupTemp.g and
    sourceTable.h = #dupTemp.h and
    sourceTable.i   = #dupTemp.i and
    sourceTable.PriKey != #dupTemp.MaxPriKey
```

Any tips on how to speed this up, or a faster way?  Remember I will have to run this again for rows that are not exact duplicates.

Thanks so much.

UPDATE:
  I had to stop step 2 from running at the 9 hour mark.
  I tried OMG Ponies' method and it finished after only 40 minutes.
  I tried my step 2 with Andomar's batch delete, it ran the 9 hours before I stopped it.
UPDATE:
  Ran a similar query with one less field to get rid of a different set of duplicates and the query ran for only 4 minutes (8000 rows) using OMG Ponies' method.

I will try the cte technique the next chance I get, however, I suspect OMG Ponies' method will be tough to beat.

Comment: A couple of easy optimisations to your queries above - you needn't have a, b, c etc. in the `SELECT` of the top query - you just need the PriKey, and drop the HAVING - then, in the second query just `DELETE FROM sourceTable WHERE PriKey NOT IN (SELECT DT.MaxPriKey FROM #dupTemp DT)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about EXISTS:

```
DELETE FROM sourceTable
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                FROM #dupTemp dt
               WHERE sourceTable.a = dt.a 
                 AND sourceTable.b = dt.b 
                 AND sourceTable.c = dt.c 
                 AND sourceTable.d = dt.d 
                 AND sourceTable.e = dt.e 
                 AND sourceTable.f = dt.f 
                 AND sourceTable.g = dt.g 
                 AND sourceTable.h = dt.h 
                 AND sourceTable.i = dt.i 
                 AND sourceTable.PriKey < dt.MaxPriKey)
```

Comment: Please explain why you think this way would be faster.

Comment: @sub13: EXISTS is different from JOIN or IN - it returns true on the first match of the criteria.  The theory is less work should equal a faster query.  On a related note, [this article](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/) will explain & contrast some options.

Comment: Do all of the columns within EXISTS() need to be non-null?

Comment: @subt13: No, but a column if NULL is present in the data that you're removing - that'd be good to know for performance sake only.

Comment: Could this be combined with Andomar's batch delete answer and a_horse_with_no_name's real table vs temp table answer?

Answer (score 4):

Can you afford to have the original table unavailable for a short time?

I think the fastest solution is to create a new table without the duplicates. Basically the approach that you use with the temp table, but creating a "regular" table instead.

Then drop the original table and rename the intermediate table to have the same name as the old table.

Comment: Yes. Is a regular table faster than a temp table or something?  Please excuse my ignorance :)

Comment: Probably going to be the quickest solution proposed thus far - if there are foreign keys etc. this gets painful and prone to error if you're not careful, but definitely worth consideration.

Comment: @subt13: you need the regular table because you are going to keep it ;) (in contrast to your temp table)

@WillA: yes you are right, one needs to be careful with constraints.

Comment: I see.  I don't have to worry about contraints or foreign keys yet.

Answer (score 3):

The bottleneck in bulk row deletion is usually the transaction that SQL Server has to build up.  You might be able to speed it up considerably by splitting the removal into smaller transactions.  For example, to delete 100 rows at a time:

```
while 1=1
    begin

    delete top 100
    from sourceTable 
    ...

    if @@rowcount = 0
        break
    end
```

Comment: That's a very interesting idea.  I will for sure try this.

Comment: BTW: I don't think delete top 100 is valid syntax

Comment: @subt13: It is - see [SQL Server 2008 BOL - DELETE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx)

Comment: The TOP syntax for SQL Server must include parentheses with DELETE or UPDATE, so it should be `DELETE TOP (100) ...`.

Answer (score 2):

...based on OMG Ponies comment above, a CTE method that's a little more compact.  This method works wonders on tables where you've (for whatever reason) no primary key - where you can have rows which are identical on all columns.

```
;WITH cte AS (
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
          (PARTITION BY a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i ORDER BY prikey DESC) AS sequence
    FROM sourceTable
)
DELETE
FROM cte
WHERE sequence > 1
```

Comment: Cool.  I thought I was helping out, and I end up getting helped.  This is a better performer than my suggestion.

Comment: This is very compact, but I'm more interested in speed.  From what I've read and seen with ctes, they are merely syntactical sugar in my case.  Please correct me if I'm wrong, however.

Comment: @subt13: You'll have to let us know after comparing the actual query plan between the various options.

Answer (score 0):

Well lots of differnt things. First would something like this work (do a select o make sure, maybe even put into a temp table of it's own, #recordsToDelete):

```
delete  
from sourceTable 
left join #dupTemp on   
       sourceTable.PriKey = #dupTemp.MaxPriKey   
where #dupTemp.MaxPriKey  is null
```

Next you can index temp tables, put an index on prikey

If you have records in a temp table of the ones you want to delete, you can delete in batches which is often faster than locking up the whole table with a delete.

Comment: When dealing with non-null columns, `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` are more efficient: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version where you can combine both steps into a single step.

```
WITH cte AS
    ( SELECT prikey, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i ORDER BY
        prikey DESC) AS sequence
    FROM sourceTable
    )

DELETE
FROM sourceTable
WHERE prikey IN
    ( SELECT prikey
    FROM cte
    WHERE sequence > 1
    ) ;
```

By the way, do you have any indexes that can be temporarily removed?

Comment: Martin Smith showed the the other day that the CTE can be referenced as the DELETE source, functioning like an updateable view.

Comment: Ya, this is a cool feature I just wasn't sure about the efficiency compared to an old fashion #temp table.  It takes a while to do anything on this many rows.  I have a clustered index.  If more are needed I can certainly add them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Oracle database, I recently found out that following statement performs best, from total durtion time as well as CPU consumption point of view.
I've performed several test with different data sizes from tens of rows to thousands, always in a loop. I used TKProf tool to analyze the results.

When compared to ROW_NUMBER() solution above, this approach took 2/3 of the original time and consumed about 50% of the CPU time. It seemed to behave linearly, ie it should give similar results with any input data size.

Feel free to give me your feedback. I wonder if there is a better method.

```
DELETE FROM sourceTable
WHERE
    ROWID IN(
        -- delete all
        SELECT ROWID
        FROM sourceTable t
        MINUS
        -- but keep every unique row
        SELECT
            rid
        FROM
            (
            SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i, MAX(ROWID) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY ROWID) AS RID
            FROM sourceTable t
            GROUP BY a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i
            )
    )
;
```